# Optimising a linq query to be as fast as doing the same in sql

Tags: sql, vb.net, linq

I'm trying to refine my knowledge and use of Linq.  I have an Entity Framework model built from a standard sql database.

In standard sql I can execute the following query:

```
    DECLARE 
 @VesselId int = 1


  SELECT COALESCE(c.CompanyName,c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName) FROM dbo.Contacts c
  WHERE c.ContactId = (SELECT v.OwnerId FROM dbo.Vessels v WHERE v.VesselId = @VesselId)
```

and according to ssms that takes 0.00.00.029 seconds to execute.

Now I have tried converting this to linq to be run from within my model and so far have come up with this (which I have been testing in Linqpad (Hence the dump statement)):

```
Sub Main
    Dim name As String = GetOwnersName(1)
    name.Dump
End Sub


Private Function GetOwnersName(ByVal id As Integer) As String
    Dim myContact As Contact

    Dim query = From c In Contacts
                   Where c.ContactId = (From v In Vessels
                                        Where v.VesselId = id
                                        Select v.OwnerId
            ).FirstOrDefault
                   Select c

    myContact = query.FirstOrDefault

    Return  If(myContact.CompanyName, myContact.FirstName + " " + myContact.LastName)


End Function
```

This executes in 0.00.00.065 seconds. I know that the first sql query is being executed directly on the sql server, but I suspect that the linq could be optimised to make it much more efficient.  I'm hoping that by working with something that I can clearly understand in both environments (and I'll admit to being happier with sql) that I can improve my linq.  The contacts table on the server has some 40 plus fields and I'm sure returning all of these in the linq example is not helping it speed wise.

Can anyone suggest how the linq could be improved, and if it can explain why it can be so that I can learn from this.

Thanks

EDIT
Latest revision to the linq.  Could this be improved upon?

```
Sub Main
    Dim name As String = GetOwnersName(4)
    name.Dump
End Sub


Private Function GetOwnersName(ByVal id As Integer) As String

    Dim query = From c In Contacts
                   Where c.ContactId = (From v In Vessels
                                        Where v.VesselId = id
                                        Select v.OwnerId
            ).FirstOrDefault
                   Select (If( c.CompanyName, c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName))

    Return query.FirstOrDefault
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the fields from the other tables to the table that you're trying to query.
I know that having redundant fields sounds horrible but It's really a life saver when having to query against those tables often. 
Reduce the amount of calculations that need to be made in a query by adding the resulting value to the row.

As long as you handle your triggers well for values that are changing then you will have a somewhat bulky, but FAST database.

Answer (score 0):

The first query is essentially

```vb
(From c In Contacts
Where c.ContactId = (From v In Vessels
                    Where v.VesselId = id
                    Select v.OwnerId).FirstOrDefault
Select c)
.FirstOrDefault
```

This fetches the complete `Contact` from the database, so it's a different query altogether than the SQL you show.

The second query is more like it because you only select the required columns from `Contact`.

As always with performance questions, it's hard to tell whether anything can be improved here. The only (probably minor) improvement could be to use join in stead of a subquery. In SQL:

```sql
SELECT COALESCE(c.CompanyName,c.FirstName + ' ' + c.LastName)
FROM dbo.Contacts c
INNER JOIN dbo.Vessels v ON v.OwnerId = v.VesselId
WHERE v.VesselId = @VesselId
```

In VB:

```vb
From c In Contacts
c.Vessel.VesselId = id
Select (If( c.CompanyName, c.FirstName + " " + c.LastName))
```

(No `Join` but a navigation property).